# How do I dynamically allocate an array of strings in C?

Tags: c

If I have the number of items in a var called "totalstrings" and a var called "string size" that is the string size of each item, how do I dynamically allocate an array called "array?"

This is an array of strings in C, not C++.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what you may have tried and what didn't work.

Comment: And, of course, why you think it didn't work.

Answer (score 32):

NOTE: My examples are not checking for NULL returns from malloc()... you really should do that though; you will crash if you try to use a NULL pointer.

First you have to create an array of char pointers, one for each string (char *):

`char **array = malloc(totalstrings * sizeof(char *));`

Next you need to allocate space for each string:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < totalstrings; ++i) {
    array[i] = (char *)malloc(stringsize+1);
}
```

When you're done using the array, you must remember to `free()` each of the pointers you've allocated. That is, loop through the array calling `free()` on each of its elements, and finally `free(array)` as well.

Comment: But `malloc` returning NULL usually is too serious an error to continue, anyway. We don't want to be over-paranoid, do we? And what really is wrong is the cast of `malloc`'s return value, which in C is completely unneccessary and usually bad practice (but nevermind I come from a C++-background, too). Otherwise good answer. +1 for rembering to correctly `free`.

Comment: Indeed, in C casting malloc result can be dangerous if one forgets to include <stdlib.h>. Good answer otherwise.

Comment: What if each string has a different size, say, I am trying to store a list of names

Comment: @Aadishri that isn't a problem; you don't need each string malloc to be the same size, you can size them however you need.

Comment: what is the case if we don't know totalstrings before ?

Comment: @sivaram you must have at least an initial number of strings to begin with, and you'll want to keep a variable with the current size of your array. If you later need to expand the space, you can `realloc()` your array to a larger size.

Answer (score 14):

The common idiom for allocating an N by M array of any type T is

```
T **a = malloc(N * sizeof *a);
if (a)
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    a[i] = malloc(M * sizeof *a[i]);
```

As of the 1989 standard, you don't need to cast the result of `malloc`, and in fact doing so is considered bad practice (it can suppress a useful diagnostic if you forget to include stdlib.h or otherwise don't have a prototype for `malloc` in scope).  Earlier versions of C had `malloc` return `char *`, so the cast was necessary, but the odds of you having to work with a pre-1989 compiler are pretty remote at this point.  C++ *does* require the cast, but if you're writing C++ you should be using the `new` operator.

Secondly, note that I'm applying the `sizeof` operator to the object being allocated;  the type of the expression `*a` is `T *`, and the type of `*a[i]` is `T` (where in your case, `T` == `char`).  This way you don't have to worry about keeping the `sizeof` expression in sync with the type of the object being allocated.  IOW, if you decide to use `wchar` instead of `char`, you only need to make that change in one place.

Answer (score 5):

```
char** stringList = (char**)malloc(totalStrings * sizeof(char*));

for( i=0; i<totalStrings; i++ ) {
  stringList[i] = (char*)malloc(stringSize[i]+1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old and was already answered. I just want to point out that `malloc` is a system call and shouldn't be used multiple times.

It would be better to allocate one big chunk of memory and make the array point to it. Something like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STR_SIZE 100 //STR_SIZE doesn't have to be a constant

int main(){
        int i;
        char **arr;
        char *long_string;
        long_string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*STR_SIZE*10);
        arr = malloc(sizeof(char *)*10);

        //Pointing each item of the array to an allocated memory. 
        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
                arr[i] = (long_string + STR_SIZE * i);
        }

        //Initialising the array
        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
                strcpy(arr[i], "This is a line in a\
 paragraph\n");
        }

        //Printing the items of the array
        for (i=0; i<10; i++){
                printf("%s \n", arr[i]);
        }

        //freeing the allocated memory
        free(long_string);
        free(arr);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: malloc() isn't a system call. The system call is brk(), which enlarges the process' data segment. malloc() is the interface to the memory allocation package [provided with the C library](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals).

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you might want to allocate space for "array", which would be an array of char * that is "totalstrings" long.

What would then be the starting and final indexes in "array"? You know the first one is 0; what's the last one?

Then, for each entry in "array", you could (if you wanted) allocate one area of memory that is "stringsize+1" (why +1, pray tell me?) long, putting the starting address of that area -- that string  -- into the correct member of "array."

That would be a good start, imo.