# How to allocate memory for an array of strings of unknown length in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, dynamic, realloc

I have an array, say, text, that contains strings read in by another function. The length of the strings is unknown and the amount of them is unknown as well. **How should I try to allocate memory to an array of strings** (and not to the strings themselves, which already exist as separate arrays)?

What I have set up right now seems to read the strings just fine, and seems to do the post-processing I want done correctly (I tried this with a static array). However, when I try to printf the elements of text, I get a segmentation fault. To be more precise, I get a segmentation fault when I try to print out specific elements of text, such as text[3] or text[5]. I assume this means that I'm allocating memory to text incorrectly and all the strings read are not saved to text correctly?

So far I've tried different approaches, such as allocating a set amount of some `size_t=k , k*sizeof(char)` at first, and then reallocating more memory (with `realloc k*sizeof(char)) if cnt == (k-2)`, where cnt is the index of **text.

I tried to search for this, but the only similar problem I found was with a set amount of strings of unknown length.

I'd like to figure out as much as I can on my own, and didn't post the actual code because of that. However, if none of this makes any sense, I'll post it.

EDIT: Here's the code

```
int main(void){
  char **text;
  size_t k=100;
  size_t cnt=1;
  int ch;
  size_t lng;

  text=malloc(k*sizeof(char));

  printf("Input:\n");

  while(1) {

    ch = getchar();
    if (ch == EOF) {
      text[cnt++]='\0';
        break;
    }

    if (cnt == k - 2) {
      k *= 2;
      text = realloc(text, (k * sizeof(char))); /* I guess at least this is incorrect?*/
    }

    text[cnt]=readInput(ch); /* read(ch) just reads the line*/
    lng=strlen(text[cnt]);
    printf("%d,%d\n",lng,cnt);
    cnt++;
  }

  text=realloc(text,cnt*sizeof(char));
  print(text); /*prints all the lines*/

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A segmentation fault is a specific problem. Posting your code will allow us to identify exactly what is causing your segmentation fault, rather than trying to imagine what might be causing it from your vague description. In other words, it might be more informative for you to read the specific thing you're doing wrong, rather than reading lengthy replies on how to do everything right.

Comment: On Linux, compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and learn to use the `gdb` debugger and the `valgrind` memory leak detector.

Comment: ^ I've been trying to do that, but it doesn't really say anything that's helpful to me. Backtracking with gdb after the segfault gives
#2 0x000000000040087f in print (text=0x602010) at reader.c:47#3 0x0000000000400a4e in main () at reader.c:116

But, hm, that doesn't really help me.

Comment: Your call to `read` is **horribly wrong**, since `read(2)` is a syscall with 3 arguments.

Comment: Sorry. I just named them something since the original names weren't in English. read(ch) -> readinput(ch) or something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I dynamically allocate an array of strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652293/how-do-i-dynamically-allocate-an-array-of-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is you can't directly allocate the memory unless you know how much to allocate.

However, there are various ways of determining how much you need to allocate.

There are two aspects to this.  One is knowing how many strings you need to handle.  There must be some defined way of knowing; either you're given a count, or there some specific pointer value (usually NULL) that tells you when you've reached the end.

To allocate the array of pointers to pointers, it is probably simplest to count the number of necessary pointers, and then allocate the space.  Assuming a null terminated list:

```
size_t i;
for (i = 0; list[i] != NULL; i++)
    ;
char **space = malloc(i * sizeof(*space));
...error check allocation...
```

For each string, you can use `strdup()`; you assume that the strings are well-formed and hence null terminated.  Or you can write your own analogue of `strdup()`.

```
for (i = 0; list[i] != NULL; i++)
{
    space[i] = strdup(list[i]);
    ...error check allocation...
}
```

An alternative approach scans the list of pointers once, but uses `malloc()` and `realloc()` multiple times.  This is probably slower overall.

If you can't reliably tell when the list of strings ends or when the strings themselves end, you are hosed.  Completely and utterly hosed.

Comment: I know when the list of strings ends (EOF) and when a specific string ends (newline in stdin), but I don't know it in advance. Yours and Basile Starynkevitch's answers seem like something that would work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

C don't have strings. It just has pointers to (conventionally null-terminated) sequence of characters, and call them strings.

So just allocate first an array of pointers:

```
 size_t nbelem= 10; /// number of elements
 char **arr = calloc(nbelem, sizeof(char*));
```

You really want `calloc` because you really want that array to be cleared, so each pointer there is `NULL`. Of course, you test that `calloc` succeeded:

```
 if (!arr) perror("calloc failed"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

At last, you fill some of the elements of the array:

```
 arr[0] = "hello";
 arr[1] = strdup("world");
```

(Don't forget to `free` the result of `strdup` and the result of `calloc`).

You could grow your array with `realloc` (but I don't advise doing that, because when `realloc` fails you could have lost your data). You could simply grow it by allocating a bigger copy, copy it inside, and redefine the pointer, e.g.

```
 { size_t newnbelem = 3*nbelem/2+10;
   char**oldarr = arr;
   char**newarr = calloc(newnbelem, sizeof(char*));
   if (!newarr) perror("bigger calloc"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   memcpy (newarr, oldarr, sizeof(char*)*nbelem);
   free (oldarr);
   arr = newarr;
 }
```

Don't forget to compile with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux (improve your code till no warnings are given), and learn how to use the `gdb` debugger and the `valgrind` memory leak detector.

Comment: Just note that strdup isn't standard C and therefore it is not guaranteed to be portable.

Comment: Agreed in theory. Do you know a lot of implementations giving a good `calloc` and lacking of `strdup` ?

Comment: Most low-level embedded systems ("conforming freestanding implementation") will likely not have strdup, as they try to keep their implementation of the standard library minimal. On the other hand, they might not even support the whole standard library (and they don't need to).

Comment: I'll have to try and get this to work, it at least looks like it should do the trick. Wasn't familiar with strdup, seems useful. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @Lundin: IMHO, conforming freestanding implementations don't even have to provide `malloc` or `calloc`....

Answer (score 0):

In c you can not allocate an array of string directly. You should stick with pointer to char array to use it as array of string. So use

```
char* strarr[length];
```

And to mentain the array of characters
You may take the approach somewhat like this:

---

1. Allocate a block of memory through a call to `malloc()`
2. Keep track of the size of input
3. When ever you need a increament in buffer size call `realloc(ptr,size)`

Comment: Sounds exactly like the approach the poster gave as an example of those attempted.

Comment: That might not work if `length` is a variable in the same function or block.