# Return an array of char in C and malloc usage

Tags: c

First attempt:

```
char* loadValues (char* str) {

  char* toReturn[5];

  .. some operations here ..

  return toReturn

}
```

This will obviously return warnings and will not work properly since the memory location is going to be free-d after the function is finished.

So I thought of using malloc, however, I don't understand how this may work with arrays.

Second attempt:

```
char* loadValues (char* str) {

  char (*toReturn)[5] = malloc(sizeof *toReturn);

  .. some operations here ..

  return toReturn

}
```

my `toReturn` contains strings, for example `toReturn[0]` may be `"Hello"`

Any suggestion?

Comment: your function is supposed to return pointer to char but your toReturn variable is an array of pointers to char

Comment: it will still not work because it is a local variable

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I dynamically allocate an array of strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652293/how-do-i-dynamically-allocate-an-array-of-strings-in-c)

Comment: @haskellguy so make it global

Comment: You should learn how malloc works with arrays.

Comment: @AndreyChernukha: I *really* hope you're being sarcastic.

Comment: @haskellguy i'm not. what's wrong about that? it will make what you need

Comment: question must be 'Return an array of char* in C' rather than 'Return an array of char in C'. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to return an array of pointers and allocate memory for the pointees of that array. With your current code, you can't return the array of pointers as it's local. You can do it in the following way:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char** loadValues () {
  char** toReturn;
  int i;
  toReturn = malloc(5*sizeof(char*));
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    toReturn[i] = malloc(25); //Change the size as per your need
    strncpy(toReturn[i], "string",i+1); //Something to copy
  }
  return toReturn;
}

int main()
{
  int i; 
  char **arr = loadValues();
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
  }

  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    free(arr[i]);
  }

  free(arr);
  return 0;  
}
```

Notice the return type of `loadValues` and memory allocated for the array is freed in `main`.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void loadValues (char **toReturn) {
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    toReturn[i] = malloc(25); //Change the size as per your need
    strncpy(toReturn[i], "string",i+1); //Something to copy
  }
}

int main()
{
  int i; 
  char *arr[5];
  loadValues(arr);
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
  }

  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    free(arr[i]);
  }

  return 0;  
}
```

You should also check if calls to `malloc` succeeded and handle errors.

Comment: at this stage isnt that better to declare the variable `char* toReturn[5];` in main and then pass it through `loadValues(toReturn)` ?

Comment: You can do that as well. Whether you allocate array of pointers or pass it from main is your choice. With a simple modification, you can change the code to pass an array of pointers to `loadValues`.

Answer (score 1):

malloc simply works by allocating a chunk of memory and returning a pointer to the beginning. What might be tricky here is that the array you're making doesn't contain characters, it contains *pointers* to characters, which means you can't simply say

```
char* toReturn[5] = malloc(memory);
```

As far as I can see you'd need to malloc enough memory for five char pointers for toReturn, then go through the elements and malloc however much memory you think you'll need to them. Take extra care you remember to go through the array again and free all the memory when you're done with it, before freeing the array itself.