# Segmentation fault with matrix in C

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, segmentation-fault

I'm a little rusty in C and I'm trying to initialize a matrix, but I'm getting some problems with it.Did some research but I couldn't find anything.

I get a segmentation fault at:

```
char **board;
board = (char **)malloc(N*N*sizeof(char));
board[0][0] = '.'; // segmentation fault here
```

I could be doing like:

```
char board[N][N] = '.';
```

but I need to pass the matrix to a function, by reference, but I'm getting errors too, so I tried to use double pointers right from the beginning.

Thank you.

Comment: show the declaration of the function that expects to take the matrix

Comment: Search for: how to allocate 2d array.

Comment: @this it's surprisingly hard to find a thread with a good answer to that. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7653609/1505939) is the best I could find.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Take your pick: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+2d+array+malloc

Comment: With C, when dealing with 2-dimensional arrays, you need to decide if you want an array of pointers, each pointing to a separate array of `char` (or whatever datatype), or if you want a single two-dimensional array of `char` as one memory block. These are quite different beasts, even if you usually can address elements in both with same `array[row][column]` syntax.

Comment: @this 9 of the top ten results all either don't allocate an array of pointers, or cast malloc; and the other one has a large amount of other things going on in the post

Comment: @MattMcNabb Almost all of them have that, or are relevant to the question. You have to read them though.

Comment: `char (*board)[N] = malloc(N*N*sizeof(char));board[0][0] = '.';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three choices:

1. Allocate on the stack (or globally) like you don't want to do apparently. The error are probably because you think an array of arrays can be treated like a pointer to pointer, which it can not.
2. Allocate dynamically, first the first dimension and for each row allocate the second dimension. You're missing the last step in your code.
3. Allocate dynamically using a single dimension, like you do now, but use e.g. `row * column_length + column` as index.

Comment: Thank you. I had seen the second one, but was hoping for a cleaner way. It worked anyway.
Again thank you.