# C - SIGSEGV after accessing malloc'ed memory

Tags: c

Here's a snippet of code that causes segmentation fault:

```
void test_list(char **list)
{
    *list = malloc (100 * sizeof(char));
    *list[0] = 't';
    *list[1] = 'e'; // SIGSEGV here
    *list[2] = 's';
    *list[3] = 't';
}

int main()
{
    char *list;
    test_list(&list);
    return 0;
}
```

What has just happened?

Comment: Check if malloc was successful by checking its return value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I dynamically allocate an array of strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652293/how-do-i-dynamically-allocate-an-array-of-strings-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware of [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) - change:

```
*list[0] = 't';
```

to

```
(*list)[0] = 't';
```

(and so on...)