# How to create an uninitialised array of strings in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, dynamic

I'm trying to create an array of strings using calloc method and I'm getting quite a lot many errors.

```
int main() {
    int T,i;
    char *w;
    char **s;

    w=(char*)calloc(100,sizeof(char));
    scanf("%d",&T);
    s=(char**)calloc(T,sizeof(char));
    s=(char*)calloc(100,sizeof(char));
    for(i=0;i<T;i++)
    { 
      scanf("%s",w);
      s[i]=w;
    }   
}
```

In the above code T is the number of strings and w is the maximum size of the string. Please shed some light on as to how I should be declaring string arrays dynamically and statically.

Comment: `calloc(T,sizeof(char))` ==> `calloc(T,sizeof(char*))`. But anyway, you immediately overwrite that pointer.

Comment: @WeatherVane But I am still getting an error

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7653609/4142924).

Comment: 1) Declare and array of strings statically: `char[NSTRINGS][STRINGLEN]`.  2) Allocate  an array of strings dynamically: `calloc(NSTRINGS,sizeof(char*))`.  3) Allocate one string dynamically: `calloc(STRINGLEN,sizeof(char))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array stores string pointers, a new string must be allocated for each of them :

```
int main() {
    int arraySize,i;
    char *str;
    char **arrayOfPtr;
    scanf("%d", &arraySize);
    arrayOfPtr = (char**)calloc(arraySize,sizeof(char*));
    
    for(i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
    {  
      str =(char*)calloc(100,sizeof(char)); //<== string allocation
      scanf("%s", str);
      arrayOfPtr[i]= str;
    }
```

And you must free strings and array separately because the string memory is not that of the array :

```
    for (i=0;i<arraySize;i++) free(arrayOfPtr[i]);
    free(arrayOfPtr);
}
```