# value stored in heap changed automatically in c?

Tags: c, heap-memory

I am learning C from `Learn C the hard Way` book. I was doing an exercise logfind according to which i need to create a program which will take some arguments. Than it will read a file(.logfind) which will have path to some other files. This program will simply search the arguments passed in the files which are given in ~./logfind. This is the explanation according to author

```
1. This tool takes any sequence of words and assumes I mean “and” for them. So "logfind zedshaw smart guy" will find all files that have zedshaw and smart and guy in them.
2. It takes an optional argument of -o if the parameters are meant to be or logic.
3. It loads the list of allowed log files from ~/.logfind.
4. The list of file names can be anything that the glob function allows. Refer to man 3 glob to see how this works. I suggest starting with just a flat list of exact files, and then add glob functionality.
5. You should output the matching lines as you scan, and try to match them
as fast as possible.
```

I wrote a program which does this (atleast try to achieve this).

1. Read the file ~/.logfind
2. Take the Path specified by ~/.logfind and Start reading that file (i.e. /home/noobgrammer/scripts/power.sh)
3. Read every single word from the file and match it against passed arguments
4. If file contains all the arguments than add that path to another variable values.
5. And after reading all the files print paths saved in values.

**Probably my code will hurt your brain (with logic and coding style) So SORRY for that, I am still learning :-)**

**if you see some functions like check, or check_mem those are just some macros, which are defined in dbg.h**

**There will be some lines which shouldn't be there in the code, but that is because i was trying to understand the problem, So it was not simple to clean the code too much**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dbg.h"

#define LENGTH 200

int toggle = 0;
int count = 1;
int twist = 0;

int usage(void){
    FILE *file = fopen("./.usage", "r");
    check(file, "Opening .usage failed");

    char *buffer = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    check_mem(buffer);

    system("clear");
    while (fgets(buffer, 99, file) != NULL) fputs(buffer, stdout);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;

error:
    free(buffer);
    return -1;
}

int compare(char *word, int argc, char *argv[]){

    for (int i = 1 + toggle; i < argc; i++){
        // for or case
        if (strcmp(word, argv[i]) == 0) {
            count += 1;
            if (toggle == 1 || count == argc){
                count = 1;
                return 0;
            } 
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

int read_file(char **results, char *paath, char *sequence[], int argc){
    FILE *file = fopen(paath, "r");
    check(file, "Failed to open %s. Make sure there is a file with that name at right location", paath);

    char *word = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    check_mem(word);

    char *values = malloc(LENGTH*20*sizeof(char));
    check_mem(values);

    // pointing all the elements of the results array to values
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        results[i] = values + LENGTH*i;
        printf("i %d : %s", i, paath);
        getchar();
    }
    puts("Kill it");

    static int index = 0;

    while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF){
        if (compare(word, argc, sequence) == 0){
            results[index] = paath;
            twist += 1;
            index += 1;
        }
    }
    
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
error:
    return -1;
}

int path(char *sequence[], int argc){
    FILE *file = fopen("/home/noobgrammer/.logfind", "r");
    check(file, "Opening ~/.logfind failed. Make sure you have a file there");

    char **results = malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
    check_mem(results);

    char *paath = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(char));
    check_mem(paath);

    while (fgets(paath, 99, file) != NULL){
        paath[strcspn(paath, "\n")] = 0;
        read_file(results, paath, sequence, argc);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < twist; i++){
        printf("%s\n", results[i]);
    }


    fclose(file);

    return 0;

error:
    free(results);
    free(paath);

    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc == 1 || strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0) return usage();
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-o") == 0 || strcmp(argv[1], "-O")==0) toggle = 1;
    if (path(argv, argc) == -1) goto error;

    return 0;
error:
    return -1;
}
```

This is my ~/.logfind file

```
/home/noobgrammer/scripts/power.sh
/home/noobgrammer/makefile/dwm/dwm.c
/home/noobgrammer/scripts/mic_mute.sh
```

While running the code i was getting error that file is not present in the given location.  But file was present. Then i ran the code in debugger and found that code is working as intended but variable paath was changing to some gibberish value during the execution. On digging more i found that value of `paath` variable was changing while i was running this for loop

```c
    // pointing all the elements of the results array to values
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        results[i] = values + LENGTH*i;
        printf("i %d : %s", i, paath);
        getchar();
    }
```

To make it more clear. I created a string values and created another array of pointers(results) which will contain addresses of different parts of the string. i was using this approach by considering [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65529779/14276207)

This is my terminal output

```
i 0 : /home/noobgrammer/scripts/power.sh
i 1 : /home/noobgrammer/scripts/power.sh
i 2 : /home/noobgrammer/scripts/power.sh
i 3 : /home/noobgrammer/scripts/power.sh
i 4 : /home/noobgrammer/scripts/power.sh
i 5 : /home/noobgrammer/scripts/power.sh
i 6 : /home/noobgrammer/scripts/power.sh
i 7 : /home/noobgrammer/scripts/power.sh
i 8 : /home/noobgrammer/scripts/power.sh
i 9 : /home/noobgrammer/scripts/power.sh
i 10 : /home/noobgrammer/scripts/power.sh
i 11 : /home/noobgrammer/scripts/power.sh
i 12 :  �V
i 13 :  �V
i 14 :  �V
i 15 :  �V
i 16 :  �V
i 17 :  �V
i 18 :  �V
i 19 :  �V
Kill it
i 0 : /home/noobgrammer/makefile/dwm/dwm.c
i 1 : /home/noobgrammer/makefile/dwm/dwm.c
i 2 : /home/noobgrammer/makefile/dwm/dwm.c
i 3 : /home/noobgrammer/makefile/dwm/dwm.c
i 4 : /home/noobgrammer/makefile/dwm/dwm.c
i 5 : /home/noobgrammer/makefile/dwm/dwm.c
i 6 : /home/noobgrammer/makefile/dwm/dwm.c
i 7 : /home/noobgrammer/makefile/dwm/dwm.c
i 8 : /home/noobgrammer/makefile/dwm/dwm.c
i 9 : /home/noobgrammer/makefile/dwm/dwm.c
i 10 : /home/noobgrammer/makefile/dwm/dwm.c
i 11 : /home/noobgrammer/makefile/dwm/dwm.c
i 12 :  �V
i 13 :  �V
i 14 :  �V
i 15 :  �V
i 16 :  �V
i 17 :  �V
i 18 :  �V
i 19 :  �V
Kill it
[ERROR] (ex26.c:50: errno: No such file or directory) Failed to open �V. Make sure there is a file with that name at right location
ange
�V
�V
�V
�V
�V
�V
�V
�V
�V
�V
�V
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It is clear here that it can read the paath value but it is changing somehere during that for loop. I thought this might be due to memory overlap. and i checked the address of both values by adding this line`printf("add. of paath %p, add. of values[i] %p.\n", paath, values[i*LENGTH] );` but that was not the case and i guess that would be stupid if memory overlap happens in heap.
So for now i have no clue what is causing this and why this is happening.

**MY UPDATED CODE(WHICH IS WORKING FINE)**

```c
// logfind

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dbg.h"

#define LENGTH 200

int toggle = 0;
int count = 1;
int twist = 0;

int usage(void){
    FILE *file = fopen("./.usage", "r");
    check(file, "Opening .usage failed");

    char *buffer = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    check_mem(buffer);

    system("clear");
    while (fgets(buffer, 99, file) != NULL) fputs(buffer, stdout);
    free(buffer);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;

error:
    free(buffer);
    return -1;
}

int compare(char *word, int argc, char *argv[]){

    for (int i = 1 + toggle; i < argc; i++){
        // for or case
        if (strcmp(word, argv[i]) == 0) {
            // there will be problem if an argument comes more than one time because it will
            // contribute to count and thus creating a problem
            count += 1;
            if (toggle == 1 || count == argc){
                count = 1;
                return 0;
            } 
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

int read_file(char **results, char *paath, char *values, char *sequence[], int argc){
    FILE *file = fopen(paath, "r");
    debug("File Opened: %s", paath);
    check(file, "Failed to open %s. Make sure there is a file with that name at right location", paath);

    char *word = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    check_mem(word);


    static int index = 0;

    while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF){
        if (compare(word, argc, sequence) == 0){
//            results[index] = paath;
            debug("Assigning results[%i]: %s", index, paath);
            strcpy(results[index], paath);
            twist += 1;
            index += 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    free(word);

//    if (file) fclose(file);
    return 0;
error:
    return -1;
}

int path(char *sequence[], int argc){
    FILE *file = fopen("/home/bhavuksharma2202/.logfind", "r");
    check(file, "Opening ~/.logfind failed. Make sure you have a file there");

    char **results = malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
    check_mem(results);

    char *paath = malloc(LENGTH * sizeof(char));
    check_mem(paath);

    char *values = malloc(LENGTH*10*sizeof(char));
    check_mem(values);

    // pointing all the elements of the results array to values
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        results[i] = values + LENGTH*i;
    }

    while (fgets(paath, 99, file) != NULL){
        paath[strcspn(paath, "\n")] = 0;
        read_file(results, paath, values, sequence, argc);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < twist; i++){
        printf("%s\n", results[i]);
    }


    fclose(file);

    return 0;

error:
    free(results);
    free(paath);

    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc == 1 || strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0) return usage();
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-o") == 0 || strcmp(argv[1], "-O")==0) toggle = 1;
    if (path(argv, argc) == -1) goto error;

    return 0;
error:
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I think you want some kind of `malloc()/strcpy()` here: `results[index] = paath;` ==> `results[index] = malloc(strlen(paath) + 1); strcpy(results[index], paath);` ... and remember to `free()` the resources when you're done.

Comment: no i had no warnings while compiling this. I always make sure to work on warnings when i work on a code as suggested by someone here.

Comment: Your `results` array has 10 elements, but your loop is for an array of 20 elements, so halfway through you write out of bounds, which likely overwrites some other stuff.`

Comment: @MOehm Oh i completely missed that. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @tycoon I hope you learned the lesson: don't use magic numbers (like 10 and 20) scattered all over your code but use something like `#define NB_ENTRIES 20`.

Comment: but this doesn't resolve the problem. But it did helped me to narrow down the reasons. I will update when i know what is causing the problem.

Comment: Well, it resolves the problem that `paath` changes midway. There are probably other issues.

Comment: I am doing some really silly mistakes. For every file i needed to save it in the result array but after opening each file i am recreating values string and reassigning all values of results array, So technically memory leak as per my knowledge.

Comment: As far as I can see, you want to print the names of the files that match all strings. You could return a `bool` from `read_file` and handle appending to the results array in `path`, where you could also re-allocate if necessary. Or better yet: Print a matching file right away and skip the array.

Comment: @MOehm yes i want to print all the files which match the args and your idea is way better than what i am doing here.

Comment: @pmg you suggested to use strcpy() over assignment operator to copy string to heap and the book i am studying from also uses strcpy over assignment operator. Is there a reason behind that? because when i was using assignment operator for results array all the elements got overwritten by the very last value it saved. But when i used strcpy all my values were intact as those should be.

Comment: as per my guess the values i am storing to the results array are noting but pointer to paath variable So whenever i am printing the values saved by them it is just going to the address of path and printing the whatever value it contains (in this case very last path saved in paath variable)

Comment: The assignment makes the pointers the same, the `strcpy()` makes the contents of the memory pointed to the same.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is a solution, but the solution is not shown (despite a comment indicating that the updated code is below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was told to post an answer instead of prefixing [SOLVED] in question, So i am posting this answer**

There were many erros in this code including some logical errors

1. As suggested in comments the result array has 10 elements but loop is running 20 times. So in the updated code i changed the value to 10. **Again as suggested in comments, one should use macros to define a value which is going to remain constant during the course of the program**. There are few advantages of that approach - If you have to change array size you don't have to change the value everywhere, just change the value of the macro and you are good to go.
2. In the non-working code: in function `read_file` i have created a big string `values` which will save the path of the file if there is any passed argument present in the file it will add that path in file. But for every file i am reading i am calling read_file again and again, which causes values to be declared again and again. So after every call of the function variable `values` is distroyed so does the value stored in it (technically not distroying but getting allocated new memory for every call which also shows **There is memory leak in the program**). So i had to move that `values` in the function `path`.
3. In function `read_file`: I have a assignment `result[index] = paath`. So by doing this i am not saving the string in `values` **(pointed by result[index])**. I am saving the address given by paath variable not the value in it. So for every matched value result is saving the address pointed by paath variable. So results will have same address again and again. So the lesson is **If you are trying to save a string in heap use strcpy or similar function, avoid using = (assignment operator)**
4. Now the logical error: The target was to search for all the arguments in the files pointed by logfind. But my program is not doing that. although it will work fine with OR flag (-o/-O), it won't give correct result without OR flag. As it is considering that any argument passed will be present once in the file. So for `./logfind if and or` it will print a file with `if` present 3 times. Better way to avoid this is to search for only single argument during one iteration of file. Don't compare each argument in single iteration.

**Thanks everyone in question's comment section for helping me it would have been impossible to figure this out for me on my own**